# Is there any way to have audio output through one Bluetooth device and input through another

Tags: audio, headphones, bluetooth-audio, microphone

I have an Android phone and Sony WF-1000XM4 noise cancelling earbuds.

These work great when listening to music or making calls over Discord. However, I'm often in high noise environments where the mic pickup does not work and I have to use a different boom mic.

However, if I am using the earbuds to provide audio output, I can't use the bluetooth mic for input. And vice versa, I can tell my phone to use the mic but then no sound comes out of the earbuds.

I can connect both devices to my phone simultaneously, **is there any way to tell Android to use one Bluetooth device for output and another for input at the same time?**

Comment: It seems your hitting a software issue in that Android' Bluetooth profiles are preventing you from doing what you want.  Whilst it's possible for some devices to share a profile like a Bluetooth mouse and keyboard on the HID profile, it isn't possible with audio devices generally unless you have a specific device that has been designed to do things that way such as some of Samsung Galaxy devices that allow dual audio devices in the Bluetooth settings.  This is the rub in that in each audio profile you seem to be able to have one active device at a time, meaning you have have 1 not both.

Comment: @Archerbob - Is there any reason for this limitation? I can't think of one. And is it a hard OS limitation or is it possible within current Android specs with a custom app?